# PhoneGap linking with Visual Studio

Tags: cordova

i have installed Visual Studio 2013 on my Windows 8 64-bit PC.i have also installed phonegap on my pc.also the windows 8 SDK is installed.How should i run my html files as an app now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2595633, Please refer to the Microsoft download site below:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42675

You can find all the information and setup instructions regarding developing Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Cordova) in the documentation under download.

Furthermore, you need to download and install the vs2013mda_0.1.exe file and run it to install the latest Android SDK etc. required to develop Cordova apps. Make use of the automated installer or refer to the documentation on how to install and manually setup if you'd prefer to not make use of the automated installer.

Please mark as answer if this helps.

Good luck